Can the applicant add new claims to their application in response to a rejection?
Let's suppose that a patent application has 10 claims, first submitted on 01/01/2024.
A year later, the examiner rejected 1 of the 10 claims.
In response to this rejection, the applicant modified the rejected claim and added 2 more claims.
Questions.

Will the modified claim now have a new "effective filing date"?
Will the applicant be allowed to add the 2 more claims?
If (2) is true, then will those new claims will also have their own separate "effective filing date"?


You can add a claim but it has to be supported in the application as filed. This applies also to amending claims.
New matter can’t be added after filing. A new claim must be for something already explained in the application on the day of filing.
So all claims have the same effective priority date.
A special case - If you filed a provisional application that has less content than the non-provisional some claims (new or old) might be able to have a different date for prior art purposes.
In a continuation-in-part application (US) claims will have different effective priority dates.

what do you mean by "unless it has support in the application-as-filed"?

See edit to answer

It might be clearer if you wrote in your first sentence: "You can add a claim but it has to be supported in the application as filed."

Removed the double negative - thanks
